# gcc error installing R packages in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: r, ubuntu, gcc

I'm getting a `gcc`error while trying to install several R packages for example devtools and plyr give the same errors.

```
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-fstack-protector-strong'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wdate-time'
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:132: recipe for target 'devtools.o' failed
```

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 and R: 3.3.2. I had a working version of R but there were issues with some libraries, so I did: 
`apt-get remove r-base-core` and followed [this](https://blog.terminal.com/getting-an-up-to-date-r-and-rstudio-installation-on-ubuntu/) to re-install

It would be great to get a set of instructions to re-install R if needed and fix the gcc error.

BTW: I also had an anaconda version, that I've removed.

**EDIT:**

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.5-4ubuntu2) 4.8.5
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: These are both new in gcc  4.9, so you might have an older version of gcc.  They might not be completely necessary (the second one is just a warning option), try turning them off.

Comment: @david25272, how do you go about turning off those compiler command-line options?

Comment: Probably there will be a line in `/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf` that starts with `CC = gcc ...` with various options.  Alternately, it might be in the makefile that contains the `devtools.o` target.

Comment: in Makeconf there is only: `CC = gcc -std=gnu99`

Comment: @david25272 What you are proposing is not an option because I can't change the makefile for every package I'd install. Thanks for your input anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone gets this again, the simplest solution was to upgrade gcc to gcc.4.9.
Then everything works as expected.